# Excepcion "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, excepciones, nullpointerexception

Estoy intentando validad un **txtfield**:

```
private void txtMatriculaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    // Busca el codigo que hayamos tecleado en txtCodigo, si devuelve nulo es que no existe
    if (buscarMatricula(txtMatricula.getText()) != null) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ya existe esa matricula: " + txtMatricula.getText());
        // Se devuelve el foco al mismo
        txtMatricula.requestFocus();
    } else {
        // Si no se ha tecleado nada
        if (txtMatricula.getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Matrícula vacia");
            txtMatricula.requestFocus();
        } else {

            if (correcto(txtMarca.getText(), patronMatriculaUno)) {
                // Si lo tecleado coincide con el patrón, llevamos el foco al siguiente campo
                txtMarca.requestFocus();
            } else {
                // Si no coindice: mensaje y se devuelve el foco al mismo
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Matrícula incorrecta");
                txtMatricula.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pero cuando ejecuto, me muestra el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at formularios.AppVehiculos.buscarMatricula(AppVehiculos.java:58)
>       at formularios.AppVehiculos.txtMatriculaActionPerformed(AppVehiculos.java:290)
>       at formularios.AppVehiculos.access$000(AppVehiculos.java:15)
>       at formularios.AppVehiculos$1.actionPerformed(AppVehiculos.java:111)
>       at javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(JTextField.java:508)
>       at javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(JTextField.java:721)
>       at javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(JTextField.java:836)
>       at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1668)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2882)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2929)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2845)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6316)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
>       at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:835)
>       at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1103)
>       at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:974)
>       at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:800)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 49 seconds)

Por cierto el validador que uso es:

```
// Patron matricula uno
Pattern patronMatriculaUno = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}[a-zA-Z]{3}");
```

Y el metodo que le paso de correcto:

```
// Comprueba que un valor coindida con el patrón
public boolean correcto(String valor, Pattern patron) {
    boolean correcto;

    Matcher nValor = patron.matcher(valor);
    if (nValor.matches()) {
        correcto = true;
    } else {
        correcto = false;
    }

    return correcto;
}
```

Comment: Al parecer tienes una variable nula en AppVehiculos.java:58. Para mejor respuesta pon esa línea o ese archivo por favor.

Comment: Efectivamente no inicie el arrayList y por eso me devolvia el null